# JavaScript regex: replace variables of whole string in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have the following sentence:

```
var sen = "helloadd but add sumis sum";
```

I need to replace `add` and `sum` in their whole string only, but not replace `add` in `helloadd` or `sum` in `sumis`.

So I did the following and it works:

```
sen = sen.replace(/\s+add\s+/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

But I have the words to be replaced in an array: `var words = [add, sum]` and use the forEach way to replace each word appeared in the sentence:

```
words.forEach(function(word){
    // this does not work though
    sen = sen.replace(new RegExp(/\s+/ + word + /\s+/, 'g'), "<b>$1</b>");
});
```

Question here is to how to use variable together with space in the regex?

Comment: `new RegExp('\\s+'+word+'\\s+', 'g')`, or ``new RegExp(String.raw`\s+${word}\s+`, 'g')``.

Comment: your comment doesn't work, btw. it won't match the last *sum* since it isn't followed by a whitespace. the duplicate link uses word boundary and seems to work just fine.